# codeigniter returning object

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am selecting from database and data successfully coming back. I am just not sure how to access element of the array such as username or name or etc. This is the output:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 9 [fullname] => Ø®Ø§Ù„Ø¯
>   Ø§Ù„ØºØ§Ù…Ø¯ÙŠ [membership] => free [username] => kkkkk
>   [password] => 16d7a4fca7442dda3ad93c9a726597e4 [email] =>
>   someone@gmail.com [about] => [city] => riyadh [profilepic] =>
>   /home2/sdds/public_html/uploads/Red_velvet_cupcakes_with_roses.jpgRed_velvet_cupcakes_with_roses.jpg
>   [mobile] => [telephone] => [address] => [gallery_link] => ) )

and this is the code in the model returning the above:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('members');
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

So what to do here? thanks in advance

Comment: foreach through the results yo.

Comment: gave me this: Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: `$query->result()` returns an _object_, not an array. Use `$query->result_array()` instead if you want an array. It's a common mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

please check this :

```
//model function in your model    
public function login()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('members');
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
   // in controller  
    $logindata = $this->YOUR_MODEL_NAME->login();
// access like this

    echo $logindata->fullname;
```

Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

piling on -- also be sure and check if you actually got anything in your model method

```
 // check how many records returned with num_rows()
 if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

       // since there is just one record, use row()
       // when 2 or more records, use result() 
       return $query->row();
    }
    else
    { return false; }
```

that way in your controller you immediately know if anything came back
and you can show the appropriate view.

```
  if(! $logindata = $this->login_model->login() ) { 
   // NO login data came back 
   //  show appropriate view

  else {
 // pass to data if you need it in the view 
  $data['logindata'] = $logindata ;
   // call and show the view  

 }
```